# Height of background image only resizes on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a div with id #hero and I've set the height of #hero to change to the window height with this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#hero").height($(window).height());
    $(window).resize(function(){
      $("#hero").height($(window).height());
})
});
```

This works fine when I first load the page, when I refresh the page, or when I resize the page. But when I navigate to the home page from another page, #hero doesn't resize.

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

It may be worth mentioning that I'm using Rails 3.0, but I don't know what that would have to do with it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you navigate to the home page? Does it actually go to the server or is it just through javascript?

Comment: Are you using Turbolinks? If you are, you may need to use the page:change event, read more here: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/#events

Comment: Yep -- it was a Turbolinks issue. That's what I get for not reading the documentation. Thanks!